# Are accumulators thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, thread-safety, accumulator

I'm using accumulators and wanted to know if these objects are thread-safe?

`accumInt` is a type of `AccumulatorParam<Integer>`.

```
// Current value accumInt -> 6
AccumulatorThread t1 = new AccumulatorThread();
t1.setAccum(accumInt); 
t1.setValueToAdd(5);

AccumulatorThread t2 = new AccumulatorThread();
t2.setAccum(accumInt);
t2.setValueToAdd(7);

new Thread(t1).start();
new Thread(t2).start();

System.out.println(accumInt.value()); // 11 or 13 or 18
```

`AccumlatorThread` class:

```
class AccumulatorThread implements Runnable {
    Accumulator<Integer> accum;
    Integer              valueToAdd;

    public Integer getValueToAdd() {
        return valueToAdd;
    }


    public void setValueToAdd(Integer valueToAdd) {
        this.valueToAdd = valueToAdd;
    }

    public Accumulator<Integer> getAccum() {
        return accum;
    }


    public void setAccum(Accumulator<Integer> accum) {
        this.accum = accum;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Value to Add in Thread : "+valueToAdd);
        accum.add(valueToAdd);
    }
}
```

The behavior shows that it is not a thread safe. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OOC why are you both setting and reading the accumulator in the same program?   Accumulators are generally added to by the worker threads and may only be read by the driver thread.

```
Worker1:   accumulator.add(increment)
Worker2:   accumulator.add(someOtherIncrement)

Driver:  println(accumulator.value)
```

Now you are asking about mulithreading for setting/reading values in different threads on the driver. To what purpose? In that case just use a local JVM `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`.

Accumulators are variables that are only “added” to through an associative operation and can therefore be efficiently supported in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Accumulators are not thread-safe. Only `SparkContext` can be used in multiple threads.

Comment: According to AccumulatorV2(https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.scala), the output of it should be a type that can be read atomically (e.g., Int, Long), or thread-safely (e.g., synchronized collections) because it will be read from other threads. Could you give any example to help understand this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other two great answers from [@javadba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465633/1305344) and [@zsxwing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27438800/1305344).

My understanding of Apache Spark is that they may or may not be thread-safe. It does *not* really matter. Since the driver is "far away" from its workers (they usually talk to each other over the network or at least between JVMs -- unless it's local mode) all updates to an accumulator arrive in messages that are processed one by one and therefore ensure single-threaded update to the accumulator.

Comment: Doesn't it matter if you are running tests in local mode?

Comment: It doesn't since the driver and the one and only executor are separated (yet work on the same JVM).

Answer (score 0):

Accumulators are not thread-safe, in fact they do not need to be thread-safe. For executors, accumulators are write only variables, they can be added by executors and they can be read by the driver. Driver makes use of DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators method to update values of accumulators after task is completed, and this method is called only from a thread that runs scheduling loop. At a time, only one task completion event is handled. That's why there is no need for accumulators to be thread-safe.