# Why Spark Accumulator's output type need to be thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

According to [AccumulatorV2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.scala), the output of it should be
a type that can be read atomically (e.g., Int, Long), or thread-safely
(e.g., synchronized collections) because it will be read from other threads.

Let's say I have a class called CheckSumAccumulator which extends from AccumulatorV2, CheckSumAccumulator's output type is CheckSum, CheckSumAccumulator  has a private field called  checkSum;  CheckSum has a private field called count and it has public setting and getter methods.

```
public class CheckSumAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2<String, CheckSum> {
   private CheckSum checkSum;
   ...
}

public class CheckSum extends Serializable {
   private long count;
   public long getCount() {
     return count;
   }
   
   public void setCount(long count) {
     this.count = count;
   } 
}
```

What could go wrong?
Does Accumulator instance runs in single thread in each Executor?

Answer (score 0):

Spark Accumulator is a shared variable that can be used to accumulate values across multiple tasks and stages in a Spark job. Because it is shared across multiple threads, it is important for it to be thread-safe to ensure that updates to the accumulator's value are atomic and consistent across all tasks and stages. If the accumulator were not thread-safe, it could lead to race conditions and inconsistent results. Thread-safety is typically achieved by using synchronization mechanisms such as locks or atomic operations.

Comment: Look at comments in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438591/are-accumulators-thread-safe, Accumulator doesn't need to be thread safe.